# How to apply custom style to <a> tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to style a href using a custom style, named myStyle :

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Red Hover</a>

<a class="myStyle" href="http://www.google.com">Blue Hover</a>

.myStyle {
a:hover {
    color: blue;
}    
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: green;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: red;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uzaG9/863/

So `Red Hover` should changed to Red on hover - this works
but 'Blue Hover' does not change on hover.

I'm using this style in attempt to change the hover :

```
.myStyle {
    a:hover {
        color: blue;
    }    
    }
```

But I don't think this format is correct ?
How can I apply a custom style to an `<a>` tag ?

Comment: You need to read up on the basics of CSS. What you have above is invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
a.myStyle:hover {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

Comment: As the answer shows, the issue was with the selector. Here is a good resource that has been very helpful for me to better understand css selectors. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/ Hope it helps